# Angularjs datatables add Events

Tags: angularjs, datatables

I use the Angular datatables module.
https://github.com/l-lin/angular-datatables

I want to catch the initComplete event, when the datatable finished draw all the elements.

Thanks

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`initComplete` is not an event it's a callback, which is fired when the table is initialized.

```
$scope.dtOptions = DTOptionsBuilder.newOptions()
        .withBootstrap()
        .withOption('initComplete', function(){
            // Do your stuff here, you could even fire your own event here with $rootScope.$broadcast('tableInitComplete');
        });
```

Comment: I had to remove the ````withBootstrap()```` call and it works perfectly.